# How to use q'[]' operator with variable in function

Tags: oracle

I have written an oracle function for which i need data as q'[var]' where var is a variable. But oracle is not reading it as a variable.

I have tried q'['||var||']' which doesn't work. Putting q'[ in string also doesn't work because it doesn't read q as an operator then. i have tried number of combinations but none seem to work. What am I doing wrong.

I am using oracle 11g.

EDIT:Actually I am using sql loader to insert data. In its control file before insert I have to remove single quotes from the data.

In control file REPLACE_QUOTE function is called which sends the column data which it receives from file.Below I have added the content of control file for that particular column.

```
 COLUMN "MY_SCHEMA.REPLACE_QUOTE(:COLUMN)"
```

Here is the function.

```
create or replace function REPLACE_QUOTE(v_str in varchar2) return varchar2 
is
reason varchar2(240);
begin
dbms_output.put_line(v_str); 
reason := REPLACE(q'[v_str]','''',null);
RETURN reason;
END;
```

I have tried the replace function directly in the sql loader control file, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried REPLACE_QUOTE(Q'[:COLUMN]), which also doesn't work.

Here is the data before removing quotes.

```
  'Failed to connect to 'http://172.17.70.74:80/xyz.x''
```

I need to remove quotes because this column couldn't be inserted as such in database.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the function that you have written. I'm curious as to why you think you need to use the quote mechanism against something that's already a variable - you would typically only use that when you've got a string literal. If you already have a string containing quotes in a variable, then you don't need to work around the quotes, since that step has already been done. E.g. `v_string := q'{This string's contents include a single quote}';` but `v_new_string := v_string||' OK!';`

Comment: Why do you need to remove single quotes from your data? Please provide some sample data that you're trying to load *before* you remove any quotes.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to remove the quotes at all - maybe this will help: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/153592/

Comment: @Boneist I have 48 columns in this table and some columns also have processing before inserting. I need to insert data as fast as possible. Processing each column may slow it a little.

Comment: If you've got to strip the quotes, you've got to strip the quotes. Have you tried the method suggested in that forum post? I'd test to see which method has the best performance.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to implement that, there are some hiccups because of the processing i was doing on other columns earlier. Will post when I am able to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. In the control file I removed OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'" like

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," TRAILING NULLCOLS
```

and added it to each column except the column which had single quotes in it like

```
 column1 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'",column2 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "'",
 columnwithquotes char "substr(:columnwithquotes , 2, length(:columnwithquotes ) - 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REPLACE_QUOTE(
  v_str IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str); 
  RETURN REPLACE( v_str, '''' );
END; 
/
```

`v_str` acts as a bind variable so whatever contents is passed into the `REPLACE_QUOTE` function can just be passed directly to the internal call to `REPLACE` without changing the delimiters for the string literal.

You can then call it as:

```
REPLACE_QUOTE( q['Failed to connect to 'http://172.17.70.74:80/xyz.x']' );
```

or

```
REPLACE_QUOTE( 'Failed to connect to ''http://172.17.70.74:80/xyz.x''' );
```

Comment: Tried both ways after changing the function. Same error- no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field